# How to read dynamic values on a site?

Tags: python, html, dynamic, scrape

What's the best way to scrape dynamic data from a site?

I want to read the ticker value on the top of this page:

https://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXBOM%3ASENSEX&ei=M1B1U_iEG8OPkAWhuYGIDA

using python. I can't seem to be able to figure a clear way out.

Comment: @minitech Google Finance API was [shut down](https://developers.google.com/finance/) I'm afraid

Comment: [yahoo's](http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/) still works, bloomberg has [their proprietary (but free) API](http://www.openbloomberg.com/open-api/), and I'm sure there are scores of other options that don't involve scraping an HTML page.

Answer (score 4):

Since Google Finance API was [shut down](https://developers.google.com/finance/), here's an option to get it via [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) and [`BeautifulSoup`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = 'https://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXBOM%3ASENSEX&ei=M1B1U_iEG8OPkAWhuYGIDA'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
>>> soup.find('div', id='price-panel').span.text.strip()
u'25,050.96'
```

Just as an alternative, consider using [Yahoo Finance API](https://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=API), see [`ystockquote`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ystockquote) module.